# Parallel processes that make use of the same base directory?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am faced with the following problem. I want to run some code concurrently, each of these codes make use of some folder in a base directory (they modify it, delete it, etc.). The folder's name cannot be changed since its used by some other code I cannot touch.

Just running the processes in parallel does not work because everyone is working on that same input resource.

I am thinking a way to tackle this would be to give each process access to some sort of frozen version of that base directory, every code does what it needs and then I get rid of those frozen instances. Is there such a thing in Python?

Some general code to give more insight:
(this fails due to the same folder being created twice and sorry for the syntax errors)

```py
from multiprocessing import Process
import os
from time import sleep

def data_processing(directory):
    os.mkdir(directory)
    sleep(5) #do some stuff
    os.rmtree(directory)

def main():
    p = Process()
    for folder in ['a', 'a']:
        p.start(data_processing, args=(folder,))
    p.join()
if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Comment: Do I understand it right that each worker process has to call the "other code" with the fixed directory name? Is there no way to create two directories with the same name in different directories?

Comment: Correct, each worker process calls the other code. Other code makes use of that folder in the base directory.

Comment: And there is no way to use a different base directory for one worker so that the "other code" uses another directory with the same name? In other words: Can the "other code" run in parallel to itself?

Comment: "other code" can run in parallel to itself and will work correctly given that the correct folder structure is available and that it can find the input files in the mention folder. 
Each worker could have its own base directory. That is sort of what I was going for with virtual frozen directories.

Comment: I have problems yet to understand the actual issue. Directory creation and deletion can of course be done in the main process. Modifying a file can be guarded with synchronization primitives or a queue.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to create a temporary folder for each of the processes.

```py
from multiprocessing import Process
import os
from time import sleep
import tempfile

def data_processing(directory):
    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectoy() as temp_folder:
       
       shutil.copytree(src, temp_folder) #copy everything you need 
       os.mkdir(directory)
       sleep(5) #do some stuff
       os.rmtree(directory)

def main():
    p = Process()
    for folder in ['a', 'a']:
        p.start(data_processing, args=(folder,))
    p.join()
if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```